# Python API GET Request - pass multiple values into single parameter

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Making the following API GET call in python to generate info for individual Agents:

```
agentid = '19727795'
fields = 'userID, agentID'
 
#add all necessary headers
header_param = {'Authorization': 'bearer ' + accessToken,'content-Type': 'application/x-www-form- 
urlencoded','Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*'}
 
# Make get http request
response = requests.get(Baseuri + '/services/person' + agentid + '?fields=' + fields , headers 
= header_param)
```

However, I need to pass a list of agentIDs into the agentID object to run the script on a daily basis.
I have tried to use a comma separated list of values into the agentID object, and it returns an invalid agentID error. What is the best way to go about this without having to make one api call per AgentID? The daily count of AgentIDs is approx. 100k.

Comment: the service has to expose some API to support bulk operation for that too happen

Comment: The API service has to have support for multiple agentIDs in the request. Look at their docs to see if they support multiple agentIDs in their request.

Comment: Does the server side is developed by yourself， and can you control it? if yes , please post the server code to show how the server process multiple agentIDs

Comment: The Server side is not controlled by me. I can only make the calls to get the data. Is there an efficient way to make individual API calls per AgentID in Python?